# Date Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to code a condition that the date for a trade being entered is the same as the trade date. My code is below. Similar to creating a filter.

```
Tradedate = ba[ba['TIMESTAMP'] <= '10.15'] & ba[ba['TRADE_ENTRY'] == 'TRADE_DATE']
```

I get the following error below. Any advice on how to only display the trades if trade date = trade entry date. Both dates are in datetime64[ns] format.

For example:

```
Trade Date        Trade Entry Date
2019-06-17        2019-06-17
2019-06-18        2019-06-19
```

The only trade I want to be displayed is the first date since the trade date and trade entry dare for the second one is different.

Thanks

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-5cdaf27939a8> in <module>
      1 df['TRADE_ENTRY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TRADE_ENTRY']).dt.date
      2 df['TRADE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TRADE_DATE']).dt.date
----> 3 Tradedate = ba[ba['TIMESTAMP'] <= '10.15'] & ba[ba['TRADE_ENTRY'] == 'TRADE_DATE']
      4 
      5 #Trade date = trade entry date as filter

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
    701 
    702             left, right = self.align(other, join="outer", level=level, copy=False)
--> 703             new_data = left._combine_frame(right, pass_op, fill_value)
    704             return left._construct_result(new_data)
    705 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _combine_frame(self, other, func, fill_value, level)
   5298         if ops.should_series_dispatch(self, other, func):
   5299             # iterate over columns
-> 5300             new_data = ops.dispatch_to_series(self, other, _arith_op)
   5301         else:
   5302             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in dispatch_to_series(left, right, func, str_rep, axis)
    414         raise NotImplementedError(right)
    415 
--> 416     new_data = expressions.evaluate(column_op, str_rep, left, right)
    417     return new_data
    418 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr)
    206     use_numexpr = use_numexpr and _bool_arith_check(op_str, a, b)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    210 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    119 
    120     if result is None:
--> 121         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    122 
    123     return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     68         _store_test_result(False)
     69     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 70         return op(a, b)
     71 
     72 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in column_op(a, b)
    383 
    384         def column_op(a, b):
--> 385             return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(len(a.columns))}
    386 
    387     elif isinstance(right, ABCSeries) and axis == "columns":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    383 
    384         def column_op(a, b):
--> 385             return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(len(a.columns))}
    386 
    387     elif isinstance(right, ABCSeries) and axis == "columns":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     62         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     63 
---> 64         return method(self, other)
     65 
     66     return new_method

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    547         rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True)
    548 
--> 549         res_values = logical_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
    550         return _construct_result(self, res_values, index=self.index, name=res_name)
    551 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in logical_op(left, right, op)
    349 
    350     if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues):
--> 351         res_values = dispatch_to_extension_op(op, lvalues, rvalues)
    352 
    353     else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\dispatch.py in dispatch_to_extension_op(op, left, right)
    123     # The op calls will raise TypeError if the op is not defined
    124     # on the ExtensionArray
--> 125     res_values = op(left, right)
    126     return res_values

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'
```

Comment: Try using `and` instead of `&`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```py
Tradedate = ba[(ba['TIMESTAMP'] <= '10.15') & (ba['TRADE_ENTRY'] == 'TRADE_DATE')]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting the answer